# edit button inside new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am making a form where i want to have a `@post` edit button inside a new form for `@article`. How to do it? I've looked around but haven't found a solution.

I'm creating a new Post for Banquet hall. The customer presses **a "next" button to create a new article** where is data of Post and new data to input. *Then they proceed to next form with personal information*. This is part of my form. All of scaffold system. **What do I need to write after both `f.submit`, or in controllers?** It would be most clear to have it all in my view.

**Articles/new.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :begin %> # The default is @post.begin, after saving goes to Article table. Customers can edit the date.
  <%= f.datetime_select :end %>   # The default is @post.end, after saving goes to Article table. Customers can edit the date.
  <%= @price_for_banquet_hall %>  # Big formula, depends on dates difference. This I want to recalculate, but I'm weak on scripting with Ajax, so i need this edit button of @post only that customers here would see the new price.
  <%= f.submit ... %>             # This should edit data of table Post (because @article not yet created, its creating here) and reload this page again(just editing data of @post).
  <%= f.submit, new_contact_path(@article) %> # This should save data to @article and proceed.
<% end %>
```

Here is my form now:

articles/new

```
<%= form_for @article, remote: true do |f| %>
<table id="table">
<%= f.datetime_select :arrival,  :default => Post.last.begin.to_datetime %> 
<%= f.datetime_select :departure,  :default => Post.last.end.to_datetime%>
<%= @price_for_banquet_hall %>
</table>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

articles/create.js.erb

```
$("#table").html("<%=j render partial: "new_article", locals:{@price_for_banquet_hall => @price_for_banquet_hall} %>")
```

I dont get still

Comment: Maybe it is possible to add an inner form inside the form to edit the table Post?

Comment: Yes, i think same. but how to add a form inside form?

Comment: @mansim your edit form is different from your new form, after submitting your new form you should redirect it and if you don't want to redirect then handle it by ajax and render your edit form after creating your article

Comment: Yes, i think of it, like calculating the price with ajax.. but i dont know how to make ajax for it.. never tryed ajax out. and i need this form to work somehow.

Comment: Instead of <%= f.submit ... %>   <%= form_for @post do |fp| ... end %>. I do not know if it is working, but i would try.

Comment: @irene your new and edit forms are totally different, you can't add one inside another. check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your form

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :begin %> # The default is @post.begin, after saving goes to Article table. Customers can edit the date.
  <%= f.datetime_select :end %>   # The default is @post.end, after saving goes to Article table. Customers can edit the date.
  <%= @price_for_banquet_hall %>  # Big formula, depends on dates difference. This I want to recalculate, but I'm weak on scripting with Ajax, so i need this edit button of @post only that customers here would see the new price.
  <%= f.submit ... %>             # This should edit data of table Post (because @article not yet created, its creating here) and reload this page again(just editing data of @post).
  <%= f.submit, new_contact_path(@article) %> # This should save data to @article and proceed.
<% end %>
```

In your form

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
```

will generate

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/articles/create" method="post">
```

so it's from here the path of your form is generated. **You can have two submit buttons in your form but they will always take you to the same action in controller.**

I need more information on how you are handling your form like is it in modal or what. If you are *using modals and you want to have two buttons one to create account and second to render a different form in a separate modal* then instead of having a second submit button what you can do is ***have a link instead which will close your new forms modal and open up your different modals form***

---

About the ajax thing if you want to handle it by ajax you simply need to put remote: true option in your form like:

```
<%= form_for @article, remote: true do |f| %>
  #your fields
<% end %>
```

This will take you to create action in your articles controller and you can handle it like this:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @article.save
      format.html{redirect_to your_path}
      format.js{} #this will allow rails to looks for a create.js.erb file in your views/article
    else
      format.html{render new}
    end
  end
end
```

And finally you can render a new partial containing your edit form in your create.js.erb file. For details refer to [**`Working with Javascript in Rails`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

**Update:**

Inside your create.js.erb file you can do something like this:

```
$("#some_id_of_parent_element").html("<%=j render partial: 'your_partial', locals:{:your_variable => partial_variable} %>")
```

**Update:**

Your form should be

```
<table id="table">
  <%= form_for @article, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.datetime_select :arrival,  :default => Post.last.begin.to_datetime %> 
    <%= f.datetime_select :departure,  :default => Post.last.end.to_datetime%>
    <%= @price_for_banquet_hall %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

and your create.js.erb file will be:

```
$("#table").html("<%=j render partial: 'your_edit_partial', locals:{@price_for_banquet_hall => price_for_banquet_hall} %>")
```

also since you are using `@price_for_banquet_hall` in your js.erb you will have to initialise it in your create action.

Comment: Hmm looks understanding part about ajax. If i want to put in place of @price_for_banquet_hall my price calculated with AJAX, what i need to write in the .js form? I need there to render price dinamically  - the difference between dates, so i wont even need the edit button anymore.. but javascript for me is yet unclear..

Comment: @mansim sorry didn't get you and what is @price_for_banquet_hall?

Comment: What should i write in .js file? With ruby i would do a=field for datebegin, b=field for date.end, c= a - b. How to bind all these 3 fields in javascript or coffee?

Comment: @mansim it'll be a js.erb file and you shouldn't write any html there, make a different partial for it and just render it like i have put in answer

Comment: <%= form_for article, remote: true do |f| %>
<table id="table">
<%= f.datetime_select :arrival,  :default =>         Post.last.begin.to_datetime %> 
<%= f.datetime_select :departure,  :default => Post.last.end.to_datetime%>
<%= price %>
</table>
<% end %>

Comment: $("#table").html("<%=j render partial: "your_partial", locals:{:price => partial_variable} %>")    What is partial and partial_variable?

Comment: @mansim your_partial is the partial name in which you have html for your second form and if it requires you to pass any variables then you pass those variables by locals

Comment: @mansim i have updated by js.erb code, you have to use single quotes('') on partial instead of double ones

Comment: I edited my first post. Controller is the same you written. I made eveyrthink like you said. I think only small part missing, but i dont undertand some parts.

Comment: @mansim why are you are rendering same partial again? i just explained you that form for your new and edit actions will be different. It's `<%= form_for @article do |f| %>` which generates path for your form and if you'll have same form then it'll take you to same action. Make a separate form for edit and render that partial

Comment: I think with AJAX i dont need anymore to edit. I need just get the price_for_banquet_hall dynamically when customer changes dates. After form is filled up, i willg et a new articles data.

Comment: Yes you did :) But i still dont know how to write this javascript for AJAX to work :) Trying somehow to figure out, if i fail, ill ask here again :)

Comment: @mansim no issues read the doc first http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: Yes, reading this 5th time and its still unclear many things there :) Every little step with RoR is 4hour+ to get it work, becouse "self-explanatory" things they dont show and i need them :)

Comment: it's not that hard trust me :)

Comment: Those RoR tutorials are like 15-30 mins long and to make them work i needed many hours, repeating and doing. Now i can write that code in 50 seconds and it seems that i was so dumb yesterday to learn that easy part whole day :D For exmaple it was like that when learning how to deploy to git and heroku. 6 hours to succeed :) Now 30 seconds to deploy, im doing it 10 times per day and thinking - it was really that hard to understand 5 lines on console? :) YES, becouse they were self-explanatory to everyone and they putted alot of extra code between those lines :D